# Js import only gets executed at the end of the file. Returns undefined at first

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react native app, I import a function from another file to my component. The problem is, this function gets imported after the component loads. My component code looks like this:

```
// Navigation imports
import { tabBarNavigationOptions } from '../../navigation';

console.log(tabBarNavigationOptions); // point1

class TestUI extends React.Component {
  static navigationOptions = tabBarNavigationOptions({ // point2
    tabBarLabel: 'Home',
    iconName: 'home'
  })

  componentDidMount() { // Also works in componentWillMount
    console.log(tabBarNavigationOptions); // point3
  }
```

I'm trying to import `tabBarNavigationOptions`. I need to use it at point2. The problem is, at pint1 and point2 it returns undefined. But at point3 (After the component load) it returns the right value.

The navigation.js looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components/native';

import IconManager from 'IconManager';


// Tab Bar navigation options
const TabBarIcon = styled(IconManager)`
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 25px;
`;

const tabBarNavigationOptions = ({ tabBarLabel, iconName }) => (
  {
    tabBarLabel,
    tabBarIcon: () => (
      <TabBarIcon iconName={iconName} />
    )
  }
);

export {
  tabBarNavigationOptions
};
```

Any idea why this is happening?

**Update**
In that same navigation.js file I create a stack navigator and exports it. When I remove that, it works fine and the value gets loaded at point1. Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: have you tried by putting in `componentWillMount`?

Comment: @JigarShah Just tried and in there also the right value is coming.

Comment: can you please update with code, not sure what you mean to say

Comment: Can you try `export const tabBarNavigationOptions = ...`, and removing the `export` statement at the end of the file? Haven't seen that patterns user before, could be some weird packager edge case. No need to change the import code.